# IOS background application can use library to download resources periodic?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am working a cocoa touch static library for the applications, and the library has a feature to download network resources by NSOperation in the period time, and provide some methods.

I knew the IOS applications enter the background has limited,(like 5 seconds in main thread, 10 min to long task...) So I want to know IF some application used my library entered in the background, My Library's period download task will be terminated or alive? And the application also used my library's function successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of moving into the background as having your app 'freeze dried" - all state is frozen at that moment. When your app moves to the foreground, then the app starts running using the now somewhat dated information. NSTimers etc will continue to work but the "gap" between the last firing and the next firing will be huge. [I believe (but don't recall for sure) that if you had had a timer set for 2 min, and you went into the background with 1 min remaining for say 10 min, that when you move to the foreground the timer will fire immediately].

What I ended up doing was keeping a NSDate object that had the time of the last firing - so I could detect large gaps due to getting moved into the background - and taking appropriate action.

Note that web fetches etc that were in process should just return a timed out status - but again, if you keep a NSDate around of the time you initiated the fetch, you can detect this case.

Comment: Thanks David.
I still has some confusion:

Comment: 1.  If I implement the timer by the gcd, it also work in your rely?

2.  If the timer period is far larger than 10 min, when the app come to the foreground, and the next fire time is correct time(equal the last firing time + period)?

example:  I have task runs with 1 hour period
And I click the home button at 2:00
And I click the app at 2:30(more than 10 min)
will the timer fire at 3:00 exactly?

Comment: If it were me, I'd make a few test cases, install the app (or a test app) on the phone, and see what happens. I believe what will happen is that if the period of time for the dispatch_timer (or NSTimer) is greater than the time you were switched out, it will fire at the calendar time you expected it to. Expired timers (of both kinds) should fire right away. You should not "lose" a timer in any case. This topic is covered somewhere in an Apple doc but I cannot find it just now.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Because I am newer to IOS, I have no idea about My design is OK. From your message, I know timer should be worked.
I will make the test cases, and add the test result in this topic.

Comment: From My testing, the NSTimer will be blocked when the app become the background, no matter you add this in which thread(separate one or main thread).

Comment: Well, what will happen is that the web activity will probably time out, but your NSTimer will fire later when the app moves into the foreground. When that happens you will see that the download or connection has failed. But yes, when you get into the background, the network activity will cease for your library.

Comment: Yes, When the app moves into the foreground, and the time exceed the time that it should be fired, the timer will fire right now.

Thanks again.